# How to force Xcode(or any other app) to be on dark theme while macOS Mojave's setting is on light mode

Tags: macos, xcode, mojave

I love Xcode 10 dark theme, but I'd like to keep the whole OS on light theme. But by default to have Xcode on Dark theme you have to set the whole OS to Dark.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open Terminal and run the following:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool FALSE
```

source: https://medium.com/@pawelurbanowicz/boost-your-productivity-with-macos-mojave-enable-dark-mode-for-xcode-only-33d86e452ea9

Comment: Doesn't have any effect for me, unfortunately :(

Comment: This doesn't work for me either.

Comment: This worked for me on Big Sur for other apps (Like Kindle and Hermes) that don't have a dark mode even when the system is set to dark. To get the bundleId: use `osascript -e 'id of app "SomeApp"'` from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39464824/6411857

Answer (score 2):

1) First ensure you have the appropriate system setup:

```
defaults write -g NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool Yes
```

2) Then use:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool FALSE
```

**Enjoy!**

---

You can also configure any other app by knowing its BundleID.
For example:

- App Store.app -> `com.apple.AppStore`
- Calendar.app -> `com.apple.iCal`
- Mail.app -> `com.apple.mail`
- Maps.app -> `com.apple.Maps`
- Notes.app -> `com.apple.Notes`
- Safari.app -> `com.apple.Safari`

---

To restore defaults:

```
defaults delete -g NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance
```

Comment: I'm on MacOS 10.15.2 Catalina and this doesn't seem to work for any apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [nightowl app](https://nightowl.kramser.xyz) to enable dark mode only for Xcode

Comment: Nightowl does allow enabling light mode for individual apps when in system-wide dark mode, but not the other way around, so that solution doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: The app [Gray](https://github.com/zenangst/Gray/) seems to be more versatile, so you can configure the desired look for a specific application regardless of the appearance of the selected OS appearance.

You can install it with Homebrew/cask like this:

```sh
brew cask install gray
```

Comment: Per its readme file, Gray utilizes the `NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance` option that others have suggested, which doesn't seem to work anymore. That method also has the above shortcoming.

Answer (score 0):

There didn't seem to be anything that can be done using preferences and such, so I made a plugin for that: https://github.com/grishka/XcodeAppearanceSwitcher

Answer (score 0):

On iOS you can

> Temporarily opt out by including the **UIUserInterfaceStyle** key (with a
>   value of **Light**) in your app’s Info.plist file

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/supporting_dark_mode_in_your_interface/choosing_a_specific_interface_style_for_your_ios_app